# how to interact with mainframe from asp.net web pages (c#)

Tags: asp.net

i have an appliaction where i am using asp.net (c#) as front end and mainframe as the backend. the client has to enter the names of the file in asp pages and it has to be downloaded. authentication to mainframe server has also to be checked

Comment: You need to be more specific to get a meaningful answer. First of all how can you communicate with the mainframe? What protocol? Basically any protocol should be doable from C#, but you might need to implement the required interface. This interface can also take care of the authentication.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information, there are many ways to connect to a mainframe.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [SNA Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266518(VS.60).aspx) is one way of doing this.